# Rendering and Updating at different rates on OS X with OpenGL

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

My goal is to build a native Cocoa app targeting OSX 10.4+ that renders using OpenGL, in order to port a game I am building. My problem is that following Apple's tech notes (see links below) I can't figure out how to seperate the updating and rendering in Cocoa. That's my question: how can a Cocoa app update at a different rate than it renders? In other words, Cocoa's rendering is event-based, and I don't want to wait on an event to update my simulation.

Here's the meat of what I got working:

```
    static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
    {
        CVReturn result = [(__bridge GameView*)displayLinkContext getFrameForTime:outputTime];
        return result;
    }

    - (CVReturn)getFrameForTime:(const CVTimeStamp*)outputTime
    {
        //TODO: find somewhere better to put this.
        //TODO: the magic number is not doing what I expect it to.
        float dt = (outputTime->videoTime - lastCapturedTime) / 36000000.0f;
        lastCapturedTime = outputTime->videoTime;
        update(dt);

        NSOpenGLContext *currentContext = [self openGLContext];
        [currentContext makeCurrentContext];

        // must lock GL context because display link is threaded
        CGLLockContext((CGLContextObj)[currentContext CGLContextObj]);

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        render();
        glFlush();

        [currentContext flushBuffer];

        CGLUnlockContext((CGLContextObj)[currentContext CGLContextObj]);
        return kCVReturnSuccess;
    }
```

What I don't like about the code above is that rendering and updating happen on the same event, and the event's intention is that the OS told my application that it should render a frame.

On Windows, putting this code below in a WinMain() would give me exactly what I'm looking for.

```
while(true) {
    process_events();  //PeekMessage, handle WM_ events
    int elapsedTime = GetElapsedSeconds();
    prepare(elapsedTime);
    if (fps_lock(elapsedTime, 60)) {
        render();
    }
    swapBuffers();
}
```

Here's what I've looked at (I would post more than just two links, because I have a bunch of research I've done, but my low rep prevented me from doing that):

- [Apple's tech note on OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1385/_index.html)
- [Apple mailing list: advice from the guy who wrote CVDisplayLink](https://lists.apple.com/archives/Mac-opengl/2009/Oct/msg00020.html)

Thanks in advance for pointing me to something I may have missed, or was off the mark about completely.

Comment: A lot of information here for a basic question. you might want to simplify it, like "How to Render and Update at different rates?" and include your code example. Good Luck. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `update()` and `prepare()` are analogous and are just about updating physics, etc., and not doing any OpenGL. And you want to just do that as fast/frequently as possible?

If your code is thread safe, you can do it based on a timer. You can use a Grand Central Dispatch [timer source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html) on a serial queue. Likewise, you can use an `NSTimer` on the run loop of a thread that runs its run loop. Now, the main thread of an app runs its run loop and the main dispatch queue is a serial queue, but you may not want to use the main thread/queue because that will interfere with UI event handling. So, you may want to use a custom queue or a thread you spawn yourself and make to run its run loop.

If you need to synchronize the rendering with the updating, you can use a synchronization primitive like a dispatch semaphore, or you can do things like submit the rendering synchronously to the same serial queue that the timer dispatch source is targeting. Or use `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to target your thread.

By the way, in your Windows pseudo-code, why do you swap buffers on passes where you haven't rendered?

Comment: Ken, your assumption about the update/prepare methods is correct (they are analagous). And yes, what I don't want is for the game to sit and update only on events like mouse or keyboard input. It caused me to look more closely at my code, and I saw that they are changing some vertex data in a dynamic draw buffer, using glBindBuffer() and glBufferSubData(). No other GL calls are made. The render() routine calls glBindBuffer() again and then invokes the shader programs. Also, about the windows pseudo-code, swap_buffers() should be in that if-block after render().

Comment: You can potentially do the OpenGL from the `update()` by following a few rules: only use a given context from a single thread at a time, make sure the context is made current for the thread if you're not sure it is (i.e. dispatch queues may run each task on a different thread), probably best to clear the context for the thread before returning if you don't own the thread. You may use shared contexts to manipulate GL objects on one thread and render on another. Be sure to `glFlush()` or `glFlushRenderAPPLE()` to make sure changes are "visible" on the other thread.

Comment: Ken, I want to thank you much for your answer. I've got things working smoothly now, and I'm quite happy with the responsiveness of the timer. I do have just one last question: in a Cocoa application using GCD, is there a best practice for where to kick off the timer? I'm invoking `dispatch_resume()` from my subclassed `NSOpenGLView` in the `prepareOpenGL()` method. Seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if Apple prescribes a specific event to respond to that is good for starting threads? I haven't come across this in any of the developer docs.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there's any specific best point for starting timers or spawning threads. I'm not sure exactly what you've ended up doing, but if you're using the timer to repeatedly invoke `update()`, then you'd start it whenever you determine you need to start updating your model. Doing it in `prepareOpenGL()` is fine, although that's more about when your view is ready, which may or may not be related to when your model needs to be updated. It's just up to what's appropriate for your app.